# Is there a hack to force Twitter not to convert words like ASP.NET to links?

Tags: unicode, twitter

Currently, Twitter converts anything that has dot inside it into a link, e.g. ASP.NET becomes http://ASP.NET, Any.DO becomes http://Any.DO etc. I currently make a space if I want the word to stay the way it should, e.g. "ASP. NET" though it is not right.

Is there a hack around this Twitter bug? Like if there would be some unicode character that looked like a dot and could be inserted there or something like that.

Comment: Type ASPdotNET?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space).  It's completely unnoticeable:  ASP.​Net

I also use this trick to get around the minimum-character limit on some sites * *cough* *.

Comment: The only disadvantage being that it eats one character from the 140 limit. But it is a nice solution, I like it.

Comment: +1 ZWSP is definitely the way to go, but it should come *before* the fullstop. That way, “.NET” stays a single word for the sake of wrapping and searching.

Comment: How do you actually type that character on laptops without numeric pads? I tried copying that character from MS Word but the space was clearly visible (the output was like "ASP .NET").

Comment: @Borek: Try copying+pasting from [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29#Spaces_in_Unicode)

Comment: You sir are a wizard.

Comment: I found a site that lets you type text with dots and adds the ZWSP for you. Just scroll down a bit to find the textbox: http://www.labnol.org/internet/twitter-auto-converts-links/20771/

Answer (score 4):

How about a [cedilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedilla) (U+00B8) (¸)? Or an [ogonek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogonek) (U+02DB) (˛)?

Comment: Close but still visibly different than dot.

Answer (score 4):

I'd try this before posting but I'm at work so I don't have access to Twitter right now: try a backspace character `(U+0008)`?

```
ASP (U+0008).NET
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will display as an inverted bullet or substitution character in many font/program combinations.

Answer (score 4):

You can type `&#46;` instead of a period (note the trailing semicolon, you need it). It's the ASCII encoding of a period, so you still get a normal period and not some weird Unicode thing that some fonts might not support. But Twitter won't interpret it as a web address. e.g. `ASP&#46;NET` becomes `ASP.NET` and not some "shortened" t.co link.

Comment: I can only see a dot instead of some ASCII encoding code? Can you provide an example of what I should type into Twitter textarea when I want to tweet "ASP.NET MVC rocks".

Comment: Oh of course the comment box also ate the escaped period. duh. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Does this actually work from Twitter web UI? I would expect it to  just display the code instead of the period.